# Ich lasse mein Auto in der Werkstatt reparieren

Tags: sentence-structure, grammatical-case

I looked for translation for this sentence and it was

> I had my car repaired

and I don't understand why it means *had sth. repaired* as there is no *werden* in the sentence to make it passive voice.

Comment: Are you sure you get the proper meaning of the English sentence?

Comment: "I let my car repair in the garage". It is future tense. Don't trust on-line translators.

Comment: @Thomas: indeed, don't. It should be something like *I'm having my car repaired in the garage*. And *Ich lasse reparieren* is *not* future tense.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You are right, should not have commented this late yesterday.

Answer (score 5):

A simple translation would be

> I'm having my car repaired in the garage.

That is not passive voice, not in German either. The main part is

> Ich lasse ... reparieren.

That is active voice. Passive would be

> Mein Auto wird ... repariert.

which is something like

> My car is being repaired ...

You could of course rewrite the sentence and then a subordinate clause can be passive:

> Ich sorge dafür, dass mein Auto repariert wird.

And then you get the *wird* you asked about. **But the sentence in your question is not passive**, and therefore there is no form of *werden* in it.

Answer (score 0):

The construction

> *jemanden/etwas* *etwas tun* lassen

can have either active or passive meaning (from the point of view of *jemanden/etwas*) in German. For instance,

> Ich lasse mein Kind spielen.

is active (*my child plays*), whereas

> Ich lasse mein Kind impfen.

is passive (*my child is vaccinated*).

You have to look at the context to tell which translation is correct.

Comment: How is it passive? I am having my child vaccinated, IOW, *I* is the subject, not *the child*, so it is active alright. Passive would be: Mein kind *wird* geimpft (My child is being vaccinated).

Comment: It's active or passive, respectively, as soon as you translate "lassen" into a subordinate clause: "Ich erlaube meinem Kind, dass es spielt" (active) vs. "Ich sorge dafür, dass mein Kind geimpft wird" (passive). Syntactically, it's always active voice, but semantically, the two cases differ.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Note that the OP expected something like "Ich lasse mein Auto in der Werkstatt repariert werden" (with an explicit passive infinitive following "lassen").

Comment: I know what the OP expected. Doesn't mean that "ich lasse reparieren" is passive voice, though. It simply isn't. You could surely formulate this in passive voice too (like many things), but that was not the question. *Ich lasse mein Kind impfen* is not passive voice either. It is that simple. *Mein Kind wird (durch mein Zutun) geimpft* is the passive equivalent.

Comment: The German phrase "Ich lasse <noun> <verb>" can mean
(A) "I let/make <noun> <verb>" or
(B) "I let/make somebody else <verb> <noun>",
depending on the context.
These are two different scenarios:
In the first case, <noun> is the agent of the action <verb>,
in the second case, <noun> is the object of the action <verb>.

Comment: The OP wrote "I don't understand why it means *had sth. repaired*
as there is no *würden* in the sentence to make it passive voice."
(OK, "würden" should rather be "werden".)
The only plausible explanation for this statement is
that the OP was familiar with pattern (A), but not with pattern (B).
If you are only aware of pattern (A), but want to use it
in a situation where <noun> is the object of <verb>, rather than
the agent, you'd use passive voice for the infinitive, i.e.,
"Ich lasse mein Auto repariert werden". ...

Comment: The explanation for the missing "werden" is the fact
that "lassen" permits also pattern (B), which has a kind of
"built-in passive" (compared with (A)).

Comment: I get what you are saying, but that doesn't change anything. The sentence in the question is not passive. Your "intrinsic passive" or whatever you call it doesn't make sense. The subject is clearly "Ich", and the sentence is not passive. "Ich" is not being vaccinated. You can modify the sentence as much as you want and then the result can be passive, but the original sentence is not.

Comment: FWIW, even in "I let/make someone else repair my car", the *subject* is *I*, and *I* is not being repaired. So it remains active.

Comment: I'm not talking about the agent of "lassen", I'm talking about the agent of "<verb>". In (A), the agent is specified (like in a typical active voice sentence), in (B) the object is specified, and the agent may either be unspecified, or specified using "von" (like in a typical passive voice sentence). In (B), German uses the active voice infinitive to express something that would be expressed using the passive voice infinitive in, say, Latin or English (cf. (A) "He ordered the prisoners to work" vs. (B) "He ordered the prisoners to be killed").

Comment: not sure how that relates to the question. Again, I get what you say, but it is irrelevant. Yes, you can reorder some clauses to become passive, but then you must reorder them first. And "he" probably ordered other people to kill the prisoners, right?